# toHaveBeenCalledWith fails due to an unexpected second parameter with empty object

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I'm testing a GridTiles component which will render a Grid component with a certain number of columns.

`grid-tiles.tsx`:

```
const GridTiles: FC<GridTilesProps> = ({ columns, tiles, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Grid templateColumns={`repeat(${columns ?? 1}, 1fr)`} {...props}>
      {tiles.map((tile) => (
        <GridItem>{tile}</GridItem>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

`grid-tiles.test.tsx`:

```
const mockedGrid = Grid as jest.MockedFunction<typeof Grid>;

describe('Grid Tiles', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  describe('When passing props with columns', () => {
    it('should render component with correct template columns', () => {
      render(<GridTiles tiles={[]} columns={2} />);

      expect(mockedGrid).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockedGrid).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        expect.objectContaining({
          templateColumns: 'repeat(2, 1fr)',
        }),
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Apparently, the Grid is being called only once, but when doing `toHaveBeenCalledWith`, it shows 2 calls, one with the correct parameters, and the other with a plain `{}`, which is the one failing.

I don't know why it shows two parameters, when it is being only called once (as I tested on the previous `expect.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`.

The test fails with this message:

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens, or how can I solve this?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text when you can post the text itself.

Comment: It's not telling you the mock got called twice (as you say, the previous expectation would have failed if so). The call it shows with the "correct parameters" is the **call you expected**, hence: `Expected:`. It's not being called _twice_, it's being called with _two parameters_ (and you said there should only be one).

Comment: If you're comfortable with Chrome's debugger, Jest does have a way to debug its scripts and step through the code: https://jestjs.io/docs/troubleshooting

Comment: I'll also point out what you are doing is far outside normal React testing prescriptions.  It is extremely unusual to mock a component.  Tests should be around the presented DOM or external code interactions, not on internal implementations.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can a react component be called with two parameters? Isn't always a single object parameter with the props?

Comment: No, props isn't the only argument. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56879095/3001761